# Concatenagem HTML + PHP

Tags: php, html, mpdf, boleto

Alguem pode me dar uma luz sobre melhor pratica de concatenação de variavel.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
    $html="
    <td>
              <span class='campotitulo'>";
              echo $dadosboleto["codigodebarras"];
              $html = $html."</span>
    </td>";
```

Tem algum jeito mais pratico? tenho 700 linhas pra concatenar html e php.

*O resultado final do $html irei usar no mPDF para gerar uma pagina em PDF.

Comment: $html="<td><span class='campotitulo'>"; echo $dadosboleto["codigodebarras"]; $html .= "</span></td>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você fazer assim

```
$html="<td><span class='campotitulo'>".$dadosboleto["codigodebarras"]."</span></td>";
```

Comment: Ajudou muito. valeu mesmo!

Comment: Fiz só minha obrigação